# Conditional fetching with Redux-Toolkit RTK-Query

Tags: reactjs, redux-toolkit, rtk-query

I'm trying to migrate from createAsuncThunks to RTK-Query. On page load I check if there's no user in store then fetch user and other data from backend.

This code works well with createAsuncThunks but how it should like with RTK-Query?

```
const InitApp = () => {
  const dispatch = useAppDispatch();
  const user = useAppSelector((state) => state.user);
  const ignore = useRef(false);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (!user && !ignore.current) {
      Promise.all([
        dispatch(getUser()),
         dispatch(getRawMedias()),
        dispatch(getFaces()),
        dispatch(getProjects()),
      ]);
    }

    return () => {
      ignore.current = true;
    };
  }, [dispatch, user]);

  if (!user) {
    return <Loader areaLoader />;
  }

  return <Outlet />;
};
```

I think this approach is wrong but it's not clear how to make it properly:

```
  const {data} = useGetUserQuery()

  useEffect(() => {
    if (!data) {
      // can't call other hooks here
    }
  }, [data])
```

Comment: did you checked https://redux-toolkit.js.org/rtk-query/usage/conditional-fetching?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Hi you can pass `skip` parameter, and combine it with initalState like so:

```
const user = useAppSelector((state) => state.user);
const { data = user } = useUserQuery(undefined, { skip: Boolean(user) });
```

now this would trigger only if there is no user, and data would be equal to user, if there is user

Comment: Link to the official documentation [Conditional Fetching | RTK](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/rtk-query/usage/conditional-fetching)